# How to configure zend application in apache server

Tags: apache, zend-framework, webserver

I made small web application but I can't configure in server.
Server error is: The requested URL mysite.com/auth/login was not found on this server. But mysite.com/index.php/auth/login is executed in server.
My .htaccess is default .htaccess. This application is correct in my local host. How to fix this error?
Server is: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at mysite.com Port 80

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to create a `virtual host`, for your application, which can be done by,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourserver
    DocumentRoot /path/to/application

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /path/to/application>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

or You need to add a .htaccess rule for the index.php in your url

which can be done by adding following in your .htaccess file,

`RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

you can find official doc [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html#learning.quickstart.create-project.vhost)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the Apache rewriting rule  mode (Mod_Rewrite) is not turned on, so you if you are the admin of your server you can turn it on  by typing

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

on terminal server  or there must be an interface to do that.